BIP for submitpackage rpc call
Is there a BIP for submitpackage RPC call? I do see BIP-431 for TRUC, and cannot find one for submitpackage.

The Bitcoin Core RPC interface is specific to Bitcoin Core, and doesn't need coordination across the ecosystem. Because of that, it is generally considered out of scope for the BIP process.
